# How to use value dynamically in json object?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have a json payload as:

```json
{
    "id_123": "sample_id"
}
```

I want to print the json payload:

```json
{
    "id": "sample_id"
}
```

The logic for this that I want is:

```js
//var id = id
{
    "id": vars.id ++ "_123"   //how to dynamically use this value to be able to print sample_id viz payload."id_123"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand the question well but you can try something similar to below -

```
  %dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload mapObject using (key = $$){
    a : $$,
    value : payload."$key"

}
```

Or you can also try this-

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var key = "id_" ++ "123"
---
{
    value : payload."$key"

}
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dynamic Selector to get a key from an object using an expression:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data=
    {
        "id_123": "sample_id"
    }
var key="id"
---
{
    "id": data[key++"_123"]
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "id": "sample_id"
}
```